# Como mudar o idioma do Microsoft SQL Server Management Studio?

Tags: sql-server, sql-server-2014

O arquivo de imagem .ISO do Microsoft SQL Server 2014 Enterprise disponibilizado para download através do Microsoft DreamSpark existe apenas na versão pt-BR.

Teria como alterar apenas o idioma da interface do Management Studio? Já tentei mudar a propriedade "Default Language" nas propriedades do servidor, mas aparentemente isso muda apenas a maneira com que o SQL irá trabalhar com data, hora, formatos monetários e afins.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Infelizmente o SQL Server não possui Language Packs para a interface do SSMS.

Tente baixar no dreamspark a ISO em inglês.

Outra alternativa é baixar somente [SQL Server Management Studio Express](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-US/evalcenter/dn434042.aspx) em inglês.

Comment: Vou tentar fazer isso assim que chegar em casa, se der certo eu aviso aqui. Obrigado.